# Why does my script with flask doesn't open the html file that I need?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I made a script with SQLite3 and flask and I want to open the file 'login.html' from my folder named 'templates', this is the script that I made:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

def iniciar_sesion(base, usuario, contraseña):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(base)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE users = ? AND password = ?"
        cursor.execute(consulta, (usuario, contraseña))
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        if row:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Error en el inicio de sesión:", e)
        return False

nombre_base_de_datos = "base_datos.db"

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = request.form['username']
        contraseña = request.form['password']

        resultado_inicio_sesion = iniciar_sesion(nombre_base_de_datos, usuario, contraseña)

        if resultado_inicio_sesion:
            return redirect(url_for('mensaje'))
        else:
            mensaje = 'Credenciales incorrectas'
            return render_template('login.html', mensaje=mensaje)

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/mensaje')
def mensaje():
    mensaje = 'Mensaje de ejemplo'
    return render_template('mensaje.html', mensaje=mensaje)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Just so you know, I made another file with a much simplier code and it appears that this does not work neither.

This is the content of the folder:

```
------------------- ----------- ----------- ------- ------- ----------- ------------- ------------- ----------------
‎venv                ‎    26.8 MB ‎    30.0 MB ‎  1,828 ‎    224 ‎     99.9 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    ‎           
‎base_datos.db       ‎    12.0 KB ‎    12.0 KB ‎      1 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    ‎
‎templates           ‎     1.6 KB ‎     8.0 KB ‎      3 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    ‎
‎app.py              ‎     1.4 KB ‎     4.0 KB ‎      1 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    
‎SQL_inje.py         ‎     4.0 KB ‎     4.0 KB ‎      1 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    
‎SQL_injection.sql   ‎  210 Bytes ‎    0 Bytes ‎      1 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎22/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023    
‎usuarios.db         ‎    0 Bytes ‎    0 Bytes ‎      1 ‎      0 ‎      0.0 % ‎23/11/2023    ‎23/11/2023
```

I've tried:

- Trying different ports such as: 80, 5001.
- Look for restrictions or blocks from the Windows Firewall.
- Made another file with simplier code, didn't work.
- Opening VsCode as admin.

When I run the script it stays like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxjG3.png

Comment: folder has to be called `templates`

Comment: It is called templates.

Comment: So, what exactly DOES happen?  Do you get a Python error?  Do you get an HTTP error?

Comment: I edited the post so you can see what I mean. The file doesn't open, but it does not show me anything.

Comment: so when you enter `http://localhost:5000/login` in the browser no page appears? Do you get a 404 error? Because the picture you provided just shows the normal output of flask when flask the server is started

Comment: Nothing appears, not even an error outpu or something, so I don't know what it could be.